# Spring-security-core:3.0.3. Ajax. How to disable redirection to page after /login/authenticate?

Tags: grails-3.0

How to disable redirection to page after /login/authenticate?

And get a response { "success": true, "message": "Welcome"}, without redirecting to page.

For failing to get { "success": false, "message": "Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password"}, without redirecting to page.

At the established parameters:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true 

grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
[pattern:'/**/js/**',      filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
[pattern:'/**/css/**',     filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
[pattern:'/**/images/**',  filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
[pattern:'/assets/**',     filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
[pattern:'/account/**',    filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
[pattern:'/api/**',        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'] ]
```

Not propose Spring Security REST plugin.

Comment: I don't believe `j_spring_security_check` is used by the plugin at all since version 3.  It is `/login/authenticate` now.  But if you are trying to visit that endpoint for some other reason, my guess would be that `/j_spring_security_check` is getting intercepted by the default "deny" policy of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented your ajax login like this?
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#ajax

Default behaviour should be almost as you described (there's no success:false when failing, only error).

When successfully authenticated, ajaxSuccess -method from LoginController is called. When failing authfail or ajaxDenied -is called. And it only renders JSON.

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy

Comment: Does not work:  class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = { "/login/authenticate"(controller: "logIn", action: "index") }}  https://gist.github.com/igilfanov/2eb83242cfacf35780b3

Comment: If you set grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.useForward = true, the authentication is successful without redirecting to page, but for some reason, subsequent requests are ignored with the http-status 401

Comment: And it did not help: "/login"(resources:"logIn")